# Google Data Fusion Pipeline Failed

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, google-cloud-data-fusion

Im trying to build google data fusion pipeline to load data from MS SQL server to Big Query. The source (MS Sql server - 2016 standard) is running on GCP VM. I can connect to sql instance using public IP without any issue. Im using Big Query connector as sink.

As JDBC driver I'm using Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver v 6.0.jre7 which available on data fusion HUB.

[image: my pipeline looks like this. It simple]

Here is Data Fusion instance details:

- Edition : BASIC
- Version :6.8.1 (latest version)
- Private IP Disabled

When i run the pipeline and it get fails with following error messages. Can anyone please help me to resolve this. What I'm missing in the configuration.

```
04/07/2023 0:42:40
INFO
Launch main class org.apache.spark.executor.YarnCoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main([--driver-url, spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@cdap-mypipe-98803685-d4b2-11ed-a81e-26b0641a83bd-w-1.us-central1-f.c.marine-fusion-270120.internal:35779, --executor-id, 1, --hostname, cdap-mypipe-98803685-d4b2-11ed-a81e-bd-w-0.us-central1-f.c.marine-fusion-2.internal, --cores, 1, --app-id, application_1680809963358_0002, --resourceProfileId, 0, --user-class-path, file:/hadoop/yarn/nm-local-dir/usercache/yarn/appcache/application_1680809963358_0002/container_1680809963358_0002_01_000002/__app__.jar])
04/07/2023 0:42:46
WARN
Cannot load filesystem: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.HftpFileSystem not found
04/07/2023 0:42:46
WARN
Cannot load filesystem: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.HsftpFileSystem not found
04/07/2023 0:42:48
ERROR
Aborting task
04/07/2023 0:42:48
ERROR
Task attempt_202304061942308162483986510619117_0003_r_000000_0 aborted.
04/07/2023 0:42:48
ERROR
Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
04/07/2023 0:42:48
WARN
Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0) (cdap-mypipe-98803685-d4b2-11ed-a81e-26b0641a83bd-w-1.us-central1-f.c.marine-fusion-270120.internal executor 2): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:162) at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.$anonfun$write$1(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:88) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:505) at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439) at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:508) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) Caused by: org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter$AppendWriteException: org.apache.avro.UnresolvedUnionException: Not in union ["long","null"]: 1 at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.append(DataFileWriter.java:308) at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.AvroRecordWriter.write(AvroRecordWriter.java:90) at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.AvroRecordWriter.write(AvroRecordWriter.java:37) at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.BigQueryRecordWriter.write(BigQueryRecordWriter.java:58) at io.cdap.plugin.gcp.bigquery.sink.BigQueryRecordWriter.write(BigQueryRecordWriter.java:32) at io.cdap.cdap.etl.spark.io.TrackingRecordWriter.write(TrackingRecordWriter.java:41) at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceWriteConfigUtil.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:367) at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:137) at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1473) at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:134) ... 9 more Caused by: org.apache.avro.UnresolvedUnionException: Not in union ["long","null"]: 1 at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData.resolveUnion(GenericData.java:740) at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.resolveUnion(GenericDatumWriter.java:205) at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:123) at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:75) at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.write(ReflectDatumWriter.java:159) at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeField(GenericDatumWriter.java:166) at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter.writeField(SpecificDatumWriter.java:90) at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.writeField(ReflectDatumWriter.java:191) at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:156) at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:118) at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:75) at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.write(ReflectDatumWriter.java:159) at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:62) at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileWriter.append(DataFileWriter.java:302) ... 18 more
04/07/2023 0:42:49
ERROR
Aborting task
04/07/2023 0:42:49
ERROR
Task attempt_202304061942308162483986510619117_0003_r_000000_1 aborted.
04/07/2023 0:42:49
ERROR
Exception in task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
04/07/2023 0:42:51
WARN
Cannot load filesystem: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.HftpFileSystem not found
04/07/2023 0:42:51
WARN
Cannot load filesystem: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem: Provider org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.web.HsftpFileSystem not found
04/07/2023 0:42:53
ERROR
Aborting task
```

Answer (score 0):

The warnings and errors hint that some filesystem cannot be read or written. If I remember correctly, the pipelines in google cloud need some intermediate cloud storage for transferring the data.
Did you specify a cloud storage as described [in step 8c of this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/replicating-data/sqlserver-to-bigquery?hl=en#create_the_pipeline)?

Comment: Thankx Bertollt for quick tip.
I didn't specify the cloud storage bucket for the sink as described. I leave it as default, in the runtime it will create the necessary storage buckets and drops.

However, I gave the "Cloud Data Fusion API Service Agent" role to the Data Fusion Service account.

Cloud Data Fusion API Service Agent roles
Gives Cloud Data Fusion service account access to Service Networking, Cloud Dataproc, Cloud Storage, BigQuery, Cloud Spanner, and Cloud Bigtable resources.

Answer (score 0):

Per official [docs](https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/tutorials/replicating-data/mysql-to-bigquery?hl=en#upload_the_jdbc_driver), "use JDBC driver version 8 or above". Make sure to also properly configure the source. If the connection is successful, a list of database tables is displayed.